# ball tracking using opencv on visual studio 2010 gives unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, unhandled-exception, trackball

I was working on object tracking using opencv on Visual studio 2010 using an online resource. I was able to get few programs to run, but I'm facing an issue with this one.

**Error I'm getting**

The program builds fine and starts running with my web cam switchin on, however, I get a pop up saying

[image]

**And this is what the console says**
[image]

**Code is as follows**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>

using namespace cv;
//initial min and max HSV filter values.
//these will be changed using trackbars
int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 256;
int S_MIN = 0;
int S_MAX = 256;
int V_MIN = 0;
int V_MAX = 256;
//default capture width and height
const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;
//max number of objects to be detected in frame
const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS=50;
//minimum and maximum object area
const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20*20;
const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH/1.5;
//names that will appear at the top of each window
const string windowName = "Original Image";
const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";
void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{//This function gets called whenever a
    // trackbar position is changed





}
string intToString(int number){


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
void createTrackbars(){
    //create window for trackbars


    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName,0);
    //create memory to store trackbar name on window
    char TrackbarName[50];
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX);
    //create trackbars and insert them into window
    //3 parameters are: the address of the variable that is changing when the trackbar is moved(eg.H_LOW),
    //the max value the trackbar can move (eg. H_HIGH), 
    //and the function that is called whenever the trackbar is moved(eg. on_trackbar)
    //                                  ---->    ---->     ---->      
    createTrackbar( "H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar );


}
void drawObject(int x, int y,Mat &frame){

    //use some of the openCV drawing functions to draw crosshairs
    //on your tracked image!

    //UPDATE:JUNE 18TH, 2013
    //added 'if' and 'else' statements to prevent
    //memory errors from writing off the screen (ie. (-25,-25) is not within the window!)

    circle(frame,Point(x,y),20,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(y-25>0)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,y-25),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,0),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(y+25<FRAME_HEIGHT)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,y+25),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,FRAME_HEIGHT),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(x-25>0)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x-25,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(0,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(x+25<FRAME_WIDTH)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x+25,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(FRAME_WIDTH,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);

    putText(frame,intToString(x)+","+intToString(y),Point(x,y+30),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);

}
void morphOps(Mat &thresh){

    //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
    //the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle

    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(3,3));
    //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(8,8));

    erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);
    erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);


    dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);
    dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);



}
void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed){

    Mat temp;
    threshold.copyTo(temp);
    //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    //use moments method to find our filtered object
    double refArea = 0;
    bool objectFound = false;
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
        int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
        if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS){
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

                Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                double area = moment.m00;

                //if the area is less than 20 px by 20px then it is probably just noise
                //if the area is the same as the 3/2 of the image size, probably just a bad filter
                //we only want the object with the largest area so we safe a reference area each
                //iteration and compare it to the area in the next iteration.
                if(area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area<MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area>refArea){
                    x = moment.m10/area;
                    y = moment.m01/area;
                    objectFound = true;
                    refArea = area;
                }else objectFound = false;


            }
            //let user know you found an object
            if(objectFound ==true){
                putText(cameraFeed,"Tracking Object",Point(0,50),2,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
                //draw object location on screen
                drawObject(x,y,cameraFeed);}

        }else putText(cameraFeed,"TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER",Point(0,50),1,2,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //some boolean variables for different functionality within this
    //program
    bool trackObjects = false;
    bool useMorphOps = false;
    //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
    Mat cameraFeed;
    //matrix storage for HSV image
    Mat HSV;
    //matrix storage for binary threshold image
    Mat threshold;
    //x and y values for the location of the object
    int x=0, y=0;
    //create slider bars for HSV filtering
    createTrackbars();
    //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
    VideoCapture capture;
    //open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)
    capture.open(0);
    //set height and width of capture frame
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
    //all of our operations will be performed within this loop
    while(1){
        //store image to matrix
        capture.read(cameraFeed);
        //convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
        cvtColor(cameraFeed,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        //filter HSV image between values and store filtered image to
        //threshold matrix
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
        //perform morphological operations on thresholded image to eliminate noise
        //and emphasize the filtered object(s)
        if(useMorphOps)
        morphOps(threshold);
        //pass in thresholded frame to our object tracking function
        //this function will return the x and y coordinates of the
        //filtered object
        if(trackObjects)
            trackFilteredObject(x,y,threshold,cameraFeed);

        //show frames 
        imshow(windowName2,threshold);
        imshow(windowName,cameraFeed);
        imshow(windowName1,HSV);


        //delay 30ms so that screen can refresh.
        //image will not appear without this waitKey() command
        waitKey(30);
    }






    return 0;
}
```

(Credit : Kyle Hounslow)

**Configuration**

This is done on an x64 system, but I'm doing a New->Project->VisualC++->Win32->Win32 Console Application

**Settings I have taken care of**

1. Have changed the Path variable to point to C:\opencv300\build\x64\vc10\bin
2. Under project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC ++ Directories -> Include Directories, gave the path to the include C:\opencv300\build\include
3. And under Library Directories, gave the path to bin and lib as C:\opencv300\build\x64\vc10\bin and C:\opencv300\build\x64\vc10\lib
4. Under project Properties -> Configuration Properties ->Linker ->Input -> Additional Dependancies and added the following
   [image]
5. Under project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Use Library Dependency Inputs, gave Yes(was No by default)
6. I was getting an error, machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' : So I did the following
   a.Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Target Machine ->Selected MachineX64
   b.Went to Build > Configuration Manager from the main menu in visual studio and changed Active Solution platform to x64 and Platform to x64 as follows
   [image]
7. I was getting this error, so I did Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker (General) -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"

Please advise me what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the program to run without crashing

Comment: I don't understand why persons don't simply debug their programs, and at the very least, identify the line(s) that produce the crash.  Please debug your code instead of stating how you set up your project.  If the crash is caused because there is a project configuration error, then that's one thing that comes after we know where and why the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the error message says that the input image to cvtColor doesn't have the correct format.  It's expecting a 3 or 4 channel image, usually 24bpp or 32bpp, but it's getting something else.

Perhaps the captured frame is grayscale, or the capture is failing.

To be sure, just print out the captured image details: type and number of channels

and then work your way from there.